# How Azure Function Worker 'AzureFunctionsRpcMessages' selects its port

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, grpc-python, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-python-sdk

I am running Azure Function locally on an Ubuntu machine using VSCode Azure Function Extension.

I created a local function, which runs on the default port `7071`.

When checking the the log however, I notice the following message indicating that another port is being used

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 POST http://127.0.0.1:34447/AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream application/grpc
```

The port used here `34447` keeps changing every time I run my function. It seems that the ports selected are in the range `3xxxx` to range `4xxxx`.

I am wondering how is the port is being selected? Is it customizable?

Comment: As per `AzureFunctionsRpcMessages` search in [azure-functions-core-tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/search?q=AzureFunctionsRpcMessages&type=issues) GitHub repo, port range seems random, e.g. `53520`, `55884`, `9550`

Comment: You can refer to one of the open issues [Make it more obvious 7071 is the default port](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2963) and also open an new issue for further clarification or wait for other community members' response.

Comment: The only pattern I could spot is that the Ports range seems to be in the Registered Ports range (1024 to 49151)

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I opened an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3032